# What's the medical condition Whitebeard has?

Tags: one-piece

Whitebeard had a clear medical condition and it seemingly wasn't just old age. What was it, and why does he have it?

What did it impact?

Comment: I dont think this can't be answered as of yet. Since as far as i know there hasn't been told any specifics about what is ailing him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [One Piece Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Newgate#Appearance), it is just old age.

> While not in battle, Whitebeard was typically on oxygen and attached
>   to several medical sensor machines, due to health issues concerning
>   his age.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess it would be something akin to COPD. His large body and age might've kept him from absorbing all the oxygen he needed easily which would explain the oxygen tanks

Comment: Is this based on anything canonical other than the oxygen tanks?